# unlink() doesn't delete the file

Tags: php, file-permissions, delete-file, unlink

I want to delete some files in a directory.So I used `unlink()` .But it doesn't delete the files in perticular directory.Is this a permission problem ?. If so how to solve that .

```
     $path_name="/etc/smokeping/devices/".$menu_name1;
        echo $path_name;

        // Delete file off of hard disk using PHP command unlink:
        $do = unlink($path_name);            
        if($do == "1")
            {
                echo "The file was deleted successfully.";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "There was an error trying to delete the file.";
            }
```

Comment: lots and lots of possible duplicates in the Related section and your question is giving very little information to conclude what might be wrong. It's effectively a "debug my code" plea, which won't help other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code most likely doesn't run as root and a file in `/etc` is most likely owned by root. So your PHP script cannot do anything to it.